# Seeking tool for mapping Metropolitan Statistical Areas (MSAs) to addresses

Tags: postgis, software-recommendations

My team and I ran a series of zip codes from addresses within our data set against MSA to Zip Code data found on The Census' website [here](http://www.census.gov/population/metro/data/def.html). We found that a relatively high number of the addresses did match, or potentially fall within the limits of any MSA. However, we want to verify that in fact the 1000 or so address that did fall within any MSA based on Census data simply do not lie within the geometric bounds of any particular MSA.

What tool could I use to verify this?

For example, If I have a series of addresses that I ran through an algorithm to retrieve their Lat Long points, I could use something like [LatLong.net](http://www.latlong.net/) to verify the correctness of the said algorithm to some degree.

Is there an equivalent tool other than say using PostGIS and running the Lat Longs through a geometric comparison function within Postgres (Our database is a Postgres DB by the way)?

I am not well versed in PostGIS to know offhand how to use it to solve this problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved. We lucked out in finding a list of MSAs (Metropolitan Statistical Area) and every zip code within that MSA. Thus the mapping could then be handled with our database. But this issue was about how to go about mapping MSA data to the address data that we have. And the answer was that we needed a key to map them together and [this](http://safelyhome.wordpress.com/2012/08/06/u-s-zip-codes-and-msas-on-a-convenient-table-thank-you-dol-owcp/) file provides that key - the zip code.

I hope this file and idea help anyone else out with a similar issue with say Micropolitan Statistical Areas for example.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you found a solution, but for anyone else who might find this, you can also use Geocodio to look up MSAs (both Metropolitan Statistical Areas, Micropolitan Statistical Areas, and Combined Statistical Areas, and Metropolitan Divisions).

You can see API documentation on how to add MSAs to latitude/longitude coordinates or  addresses here: https://www.geocod.io/docs/?python#census-block-tract-fips-codes-amp-msa-csa-codes

Or how to add add MSAs to latitude/longitude coordinates or addresses via spreadsheet/CSV here: https://www.geocod.io/guides/census/

Disclosure: I'm one of the founders of Geocodio.